# Когда указываю версию chef ошибка 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, vagrant

Добрый день, у меня система Windows 10 .

Мой *Vagrantfile*:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# This file originally created at http://rove.io/c2e84ee4ff854c34cd144ce345fca1c8

# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # config.vm.box_download_checksum = "a75e8dbcce749adf61a60ca0ccf25fc041e4774a"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  # config.vm.box_url = "https://packagecloud.io/chef/stable/packages/ubuntu/trusty/chef-server-core_12.4.1-1_amd64.deb/download"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8181

#  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.version = '11.18'
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks","cookbooks_addons"]
    chef.add_recipe :apt
    chef.add_recipe 'tmux'
    chef.add_recipe 'mongodb::default'
    chef.add_recipe 'redis'
    chef.add_recipe 'git'
    chef.add_recipe 'php'
    chef.add_recipe 'vim'
    chef.add_recipe 'nginx'
    chef.json = {
      :mongodb => {
        :dbpath  => "/var/lib/mongodb",
        :logpath => "/var/log/mongodb",
        :port    => "27017"
      },
      :redis   => {
        :version      =>"2.8.4",
        :bind        => "127.0.0.1",
        :port        => "6379",
        :config_path => "/etc/redis/redis.conf",
        :daemonize   => "yes",
        :timeout     => "300",
        :loglevel    => "notice",
        :password    => "170887"
      },
      :git     => {
        :version => "1.9.1",
        :prefix => "/usr/local"
      },
      :vim     => {
        :extra_packages => [
          "vim-rails"
        ]
      },
      :nginx   => {
        :version            =>"1.4.6",
        :dir                => "/etc/nginx",
        :log_dir            => "/var/log/nginx",
        :binary             => "/usr/sbin/nginx",
        :user               => "www-data",
        :init_style         => "runit",
        :pid                => "/var/run/nginx.pid",
        :worker_connections => "1024"
      },
      :php   => {
          :version => "5.5.32",
          :checksum => "b0f2c108db8e05db9f6366aaba9a754fd0ee31f3f86ee889561b608dfd6e92ee"
      },
      :phalcon   => {
          :git_ref=>  "phalcon-v2.0.4",
      }
    }
  end
end
```

В консоли ошибка. Из-за того, что указываю версию chef `chef.version = '11.18'`

```
C:\Users\Ivan\projects\get8.ru>vagrant provision
==> default: Installing Chef cookbooks with Librarian-Chef...
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
    default: Installing Chef (11.18)...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

curl -sL https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -P "chef" -c "current" -v "11.18"

Stdout from the command:

Getting information for chef current 11.18 for ubuntu...
downloading https://omnitruck.chef.io/current/chef/metadata?v=11.18&p=ubuntu&pv=14.04&m=x86_64
  to file /tmp/install.sh.1656/metadata.txt
trying wget...
ERROR 404
Omnitruck artifact does not exist for version 11.18 on platform ubuntu

Either this means:
   - We do not support ubuntu
   - We do not have an artifact for 11.18

This is often the latter case due to running a prerelease or RC version of chef
or a gem version which was only pushed to rubygems and not omnitruck.

You may be able to set your knife[:bootstrap_version] to the most recent stable
release of Chef to fix this problem (or the most recent stable major version number).

In order to test the version parameter, adventurous users may take the Metadata URL
below and modify the '&v=<number>' parameter until you successfully get a URL that
does not 404 (e.g. via curl or wget).  You should be able to use '&v=11' or '&v=12'
succesfully.

If you cannot fix this problem by setting the bootstrap_version, it probably means
that ubuntu is not supported.

Metadata URL: https://omnitruck.chef.io/current/chef/metadata?v=11.18&p=ubuntu&pv=14.04&m=x86_64


Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
```

Если не указывать версию chef, ошибка: `invalid metadata: The 'name' attribute is required in cookbook metadata`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была из-за подключенного рецепта redis `chef.add_recipe 'redis'`.
Я составил новый vagrantfile, с другими рецептами `chef.add_recipe 'redisio'`
и все заработало.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # config.vm.box_download_checksum = "a75e8dbcce749adf61a60ca0ccf25fc041e4774a"
  # config.vm.box_download_checksum_type = "SHA1"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  # config.vm.box_url = "https://packagecloud.io/chef/stable/packages/ubuntu/trusty/chef-server-core_12.0.0-1_amd64.deb/download"

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8181

  #config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"

  config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/var/www"

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks","cookbooks_addons"]
    chef.add_recipe :apt
    chef.add_recipe 'tmux'
    chef.add_recipe 'redisio'
    chef.add_recipe 'mongodb3'
    chef.add_recipe 'git'
    chef.add_recipe 'nginx-php'
    chef.add_recipe 'nginx-php::php5'
    chef.add_recipe 'nginx-php::php5-fpm'
    chef.add_recipe 'nginx-php::php5-cgi'
    chef.add_recipe 'nginx-php::pear'
    chef.add_recipe 'nginx-php::php5-mcrypt'
    chef.add_recipe 'vim'
    chef.json = {
      :redisio => {
          :package_install => false,
          :version => "2.8.4"
      },
      :mongodb3 => {
          :version => "3.0.8",
      },
      :git     => {
        :version => "1.9.1",
        :prefix => "/usr/local"
      },
      :vim     => {
        :extra_packages => [
          "vim-rails"
        ]
      },
     :nginx   => {
        :version            =>"1.4.6",
        :dir                => "/etc/nginx",
        :log_dir            => "/var/log/nginx",
        :binary             => "/usr/sbin/nginx",
        :user               => "www-data",
        :init_style         => "runit",
        :pid                => "/var/run/nginx.pid",
        :worker_connections => "1024"
     }
    }
  end
end
```

ссылка на github : https://github.com/triumphov/development_environment